# Sending Contents of a HTML page to a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

How to send contents of a HTML file to a php file. Actually I have got the total HTML content in a jquery variable using below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnExportpdf").click(function(){
var html= $("#tblExport").html();
});
});
```

I am stuck here, how can I send such big string to a new PHP page?
Please provide me a sample example or link

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a POST to the .php file.
Using the jQuery POST function.

```
var html = 'Here <b>some</b> text!';

$.post( "example.php", html, function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

More information at the jQuery Docs:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ && 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Where the content is being sent in above code? Like there are no variables containing html and no parameter is being posted

Comment: The parameter 'html' is the variable. @user3549665

Answer (score -1):

you can send data from Javascript to php via ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btnExportpdf").click(function(){
       var html= $("#tblExport").html();
       $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST",            // Methode POST or GET
           url: "some.php",        // PHP file to processing the data
           data: { "html": html }  // post variables that will handetover to php
       })
       .done(function( msg ) {     // response
          console.log(msg)         // data retuned from php
        });
    });
    });
```

[JQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I have used this code, and am able to post parameter. Now how can I open the file to which I posted parameter in a new window. Actually I want to open a php file on button click and also pass parameters to it. I am beginner to web development. Give me a easily understandable code please